# How to keep punctuation as a separate element in split_string in Prolog

Tags: string, split, prolog, swi-prolog, punctuation

I'm doing an assignment in Prolog (I'm a newbie) and I have a small problem. 
I know you can split a string to a list of elements in Prolog like this:

```
split_string("Hello, here I am!"," "," .!?-_'",Temp).
```

But this takes out the basic punctuation. It returns:

```
Temp = ['Hello','here','I','am'].
```

How can I change it in order to keep the punctuation like this:

```
Temp = ['Hello',',','here','I','am','!'].
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. It's ok! Thank you for taking the time to answer it!

Comment: To correctly tokenize the text, you would need to "declare" that comma and ! are solo characters and much more. In any case, this is not that trivial as it sounds.

Comment: as false had said, you'll have to come up with a new implementation, maybe as `split_string/5`. Are you interested in something like that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"split_string" is not standard but, in the implementation I know, you can not. From the ECLIPSe manual:

*The string String is split at the separators, and any padding characters around the resulting sub-strings are removed. **Neither the separators nor the padding characters occur in SubStrings**.*

http://www.cs.uni-potsdam.de/wv/lehre/Material/Prolog/Eclipse-Doc/bips/kernel/stratom/split_string-4.html

** Addendum **

We can play a few with string functions to recover the "list" separators:

```
split_with_delimiters(String,Delimiters,Ignore,Result) :-
   split_string(String,Delimiters,"",FirstSplit),
   split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,FirstSplit,Result).

split_with_delimiters_aux(_,"",_,[]) :- !.

split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,[""|Q],Result) :- !,
   split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,Q,Result).

split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,[H|Q],[H|Result]) :-
   string_concat( H, Rest, String ), !,
   split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,Rest,Q,Result).

split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,Split,Result) :- 
   sub_string( String, 0, 1, RestL, Delimiter ),
   sub_string( String, 1, RestL, _, Rest ),
   sub_string( Delimiter, _, _, _, Ignore ), !,
   split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,Rest,Split,Result).

split_with_delimiters_aux(Ignore,String,Split,[Delimiter|Result]) :-
   sub_string( String, 0, 1, RestL, Delimiter ),
   sub_string( String, 1, RestL, _, Rest ),
   split_with_delimiters_aux( Ignore,Rest, Split, Result ).
```

that provides following result:

```
?- split_with_delimiters("Hello, here I am!"," ,.!?-_'"," ",Res).
Res = ["Hello", ",", "here", "I", "am", "!"]
```

(things could be easier if we convert string to/from list at start/end)

Comment: [Here is the link to the documentation of the implementation that is used in the OP](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=split_string/4). There is a similar sentence in this description.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :) I figured out a solution of my own as well. I'll see which is more efficient! ;)